# move_uploaded_file change file name

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file to my server and rename the file to logo.jpg.

I have read a couple posts on the topic but cannot figure out what to change to make it work.

I have changed a couple items but i get errors and im not sure how rename the file.

The user uploads a file call something.jpg (That parts works)
I want to move it to "/path/file/saved/to/" (That parts works)
rename the file to logo.jpg (Fail)

Code from webpage

```
<form action="testup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">.
</form>

<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/path/file/saved/to/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
?>
```

Comment: @CBroe Apparently *"That parts works"* - cough

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($source, $destination)`. it's not rocket science...

Comment: You have to validate that file (name, size, etc) before doing `move_uploaded_file`. Apart of this, you probably have not enough permissions to write to `/path/file/saved/to/`.

Comment: simply use `"/path/file/saved/to/logo.jpg"` see my answer

Comment: The use of `basename` would be a given.

Comment: The OP was looking for help, not insults. A pleasant and helpful response could have been achieved by pointing him to the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php .

Comment: `rename the file to logo.jpg (Fail)` What exactly happens? Any error codes in PHP (I am not a PHP developer).Please provide the exact description of desired and actual outcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
<form action="testup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">.
</form>

<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/path/file/saved/to/logo.jpg");
```