# How can I rename and set image acceptable format and size before uploading

Tags: php

I want to upload image to server directorate but for then I want to first of all check whether the image is a JPEG, GIF, PNG and also check whether the image file size is less than 15kb before renaming and uploading it to both database and server director.
How can I do that using this my already written code here:

```
    <?php



//instatiating our database objects
$db = new Pdoconn;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //Collect Raw Data for Cleaning
    $raw_firstName   = cleandata($_POST['fname']);
    $raw_lastName    = cleandata($_POST['lname']);
    $raw_username    = cleandata($_POST['usern']);
    $raw_email       = cleandata($_POST['email']);
    $raw_pass        = cleandata($_POST['password']);
    $raw_phone       = cleandata($_POST['phone']);
    $raw_dateJoin    = cleandata($_POST['jdate']);
    $raw_role        = cleandata($_POST['role']);
    $raw_employId    = cleandata($_POST['employeeid']);

    //Sanitize the Cleaned Date
    $c_fname        = sanitizeValue($raw_firstName);
    $c_lname        = sanitizeValue($raw_lastName);
    $c_username     = sanitizeValue($raw_username);
    $c_email        = validatemail($raw_email);
    $c_password     = sanitizeValue($raw_pass);
    $c_phone        = valint($raw_phone);
    $c_jdate        = sanitizeValue($raw_dateJoin);
    $c_role         = sanitizeValue($raw_role);
    $c_employId     = sanitizeValue($raw_employId);
    $DateReg        = date('Y-m-d');

    //Hash Password
    $Hashed_Pass    = hashpassword($c_password);

    //Collect Image
    $c_img              =   $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $c_img_tmp          =   $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    //move image to permanent location
    move_uploaded_file($c_img_tmp, "assets/img/$c_img");

    $db->query('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username=:username');

    //Bind Email Value
    $db->bindValue(':username', $c_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //fetch Row
    $row            = $db->fetchSingle();

    //check role
    if($row){

        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
              <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
              <strong>Sorry!</strong> Staff with Username: <span class="text-danger">' . $c_username . '</span> already Exist. Register or Try Again
            </div>';

    }else{
    //Query to Insert/Add Employees in employees Table
    $db->query("INSERT INTO employees(id, firstName, lastName, username, email, password, employeeId, joiningDate, phone, role, staffImage, dateAdded)VALUES(NULL, :fname, :lname, :username, :email, :password, :employeeId, :joiningDate, :phone, :role, :image, :dateAdded)");

    //Bind Values to Query Parameters
    $db->bindValue(':fname', $c_fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':lname', $c_lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':username', $c_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':email', $c_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':password', $Hashed_Pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':employeeId', $c_employId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':joiningDate', $c_jdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':phone', $c_phone, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $db->bindValue(':role', $c_role, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':image', $c_img, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':dateAdded', $DateReg, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //Query to Check whether Staff Already Exist using Email


    //Run Query
    $run_employee    = $db->execute();

    if($run_employee){

        redirect('employees.php');

        keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                      <strong>Success!</strong> Staff with Username : <span class="text-danger">' . $c_username . '</span> Registered successfully.
                </div>');


    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Employee Could NOT be Registered!")';
        echo '</script>';
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This link is for type and size validation [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153224/how-to-limit-file-upload-type-file-size-in-php) and this is for new file name [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434574/move-uploaded-file-change-file-name)

Comment: You can also consider using image edit tools. e.g. https://github.com/gumlet/php-image-resize